# Complex fourier series for voltage signal

Tags: complex-numbers, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

Determine the complex fourier series for $x(t)$.

Voltage $V(t) = V_0 \cos(\omega t) , ω = 100\pi(s^{-1}) $

Voltage input signal $x(t) = |V(t)|$

I was thinking to use Eulers formula to rewrite them, but the periodicity is a bit confusing for me. I first thought that with Laplace transform I could convert the $S^{-1}$ to the Heavyside step function , which gives me $100 \pi H(t)$.

So im thinking, am I supposed to ignore the $H(t)$ part, and just rewrite $\cos(100 \pi)$ to complex fourier, and then add the Heavyside ($H(s)$) or how would one tackle this approach?

Grateful for every reply!

Comment: I have rewritten the equation using eulers formula for Cos,
cos = (e^jx + e^-jx)/2
However this feels a bit wrong, I get something that looks like this:
e^(j(100pi)/S) + e^-(j(100pi)/S)
and the full expression divided by 2. 
Feels a bit wrong.

Comment: The Fourier series of the full-wave rectified signal will necessarily have an infinite number of terms, so you actually have to go through the full process of computing the Fourier coefficients of the series by integrating $x(t)$ against all cosine functions of the periodicity that matches your original function, i.e. $\omega_1=\omega$, $\omega_2=2\omega$, $\omega_3=3\omega$, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your response, is there any easy way on doing this? So Im supposed to start by checking if the signal is odd or even, then use the correct function for it?

Comment: Like for a normal signal it will not be as hard, but I dont know what the s^-1 part means, or how it's supposed to be handled.

Comment: I mean, if you are studying Fourier series, you must have come across the formulas for how to compute the expansion coefficients of the Fourier series, so do that! As for s$^{-1}$, that's just inverse seconds, which are the units on an angular frequency $\omega$ (s is not a variable! - and this problem requires no Laplace transform, and no Heaviside function).  The period of this signal is half the period of the non-rectified cosine, so $T= 2\pi/\omega/2=\pi/omega = 0.001$ s. The cosines in the expansion are therefore of the form $\cos(2n\pi x/T)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I can handle it from here! Appreciated !!